# jQuery animation(fadeIn) pause on tab change in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I was working on an animation using jQuery, I found a weird thing:

the animation pauses when tab loses focus, this is reported:

https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9381

the problem is the animation pauses in Chrome but not in Firefox.

I am using Chrome 55.0.2883.87 and Firefox 50.1.0.

this is my code:

```
(function() {
function show_story() {
    if (count < storyline.length) {
        var story_elem = $("#story");
        story_elem.html('<p class="storyline">' + storyline[count] + '</p>');
        var story_item = $(".storyline");
        story_item.fadeIn(1500)
            .delay(time[count])
            .fadeOut(1000, show_story);
        count++;
    }
}

show_story();
})();
```

I'll be adding sound in the app and that is why I am worried

What I can do is check focus of tab after every if statement and continue animation when tab is focused. this may solve the above the problem..right?

Still, what else can I do?

Comment: Have you tried implementing your solution yet? It sounds like it would do the trick. You may not need another answer if that works.

Comment: @JacobStamm yeah I am trying that.